# Best approach to passing variables between multi-file Node.js modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, module, node-modules

I have a Node.js module that I have kept as a single file up to this point. It's getting rather large though and has a lot of functionality in it that might be better separated into other modules. For example, separating out logging initialization and functionality into it's own module.

My module has a lot of (I want to say "global" but not really) top-level variables that lots of different functions access, use and modify. If I separate out functionality into separate files/modules and require them into my primary module, what is the proper approach to passing those variables between the modules?

For example, with everything in one module/file, it's easy to do this:

```
const logger = (log, message) {........}

const makeRequestHandler = (url, filepath) {
    ....
    logger.info('some message here')
    ....
}
```

So it's pretty easy to access top-level systems like the `logger`. But, if I decided to split my `logger` and `makeRequestHandler` into their own modules/files, how would I handle this?

```
let logger = require('./mylogger') // Custom module
let makeRequest = require('./makerequest') // Another custom module

makeRequest.handler(url, filepath, logger)
```

This would work, but it doesn't seem elegant or optimal. It would get even more weird if I have a lot of different variables that I needed to pass in:

```
makeRequest.handler(url, filepath, logger, profiler, reportingBuffer, compressionHandler)
```

I've also considered passing stuff into the modules when requiring:

```
let makeRequest = require('./makeRequest')(logger)
```

or better yet:

```
let makeRequest = require('./makeRequest')(this) // I can access all variables made in my primary/top-level module
```

Is there an approach here that is more proper and better/easier to maintain? Is the last one the best approach?

Comment: dependency injection is common way how to pass vars/dependencies between modules. You can also try inversion of control (ioc) such as service locator/service provider pattern. where you will have a singleton object that will hold the variables that are needed to be used

Answer (score 0):

What about a global locator pattern or service locator/service provider pattern as pointed out in comments wherein you can have something like a service registry and include these services in any module you want to use them in.

Although I am not sure about being the best solution of all, but it is easier to implement and feels like a neater solution than passing in the `this` context around the modules.

```
//logger.js
const logger = (log, message) {........}
export logger
```

Now, in the app file is where you can initialize the logger and other service instances and register them in the global locator

```
 let logger = require('./mylogger') // Custom module
 init() {
    //init and set the logger 
    global.logger = new logger();
    ...
 }
```

And this is how you can use it in the code to makRequest

```
  let logger = global.logger;
    const makeRequestHandler = (url, filepath) {
        ....
        logger.info('some message here')
        ....
    }
```

---

What I feel is problem with these solutions :

```
//Solution 1 : As you pointed out yourself this can get messy when number of paramters increase and is not very readable or understandable.
let logger = require('./mylogger') 
let makeRequest = require('./makerequest') 
makeRequest.handler(url, filepath, logger)


//Solution 2 : Passing around the `this` context is never a good idea,for keeping sensitive data independent or scope isolation
let makeRequest = require('./makeRequest')(this)
```

---

note :
[This article](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/40610/237001) explains some aspects of this solution in detail for your consideration.
Also there are some npm modules which provide these features like  [Service Locator](https://github.com/Rapid-Application-Development-JS/ServiceLocator)
. HTH